# $ |f(x) - f(y)| \le 7| x-y |^{201} $ I need to find a linear relation between $f(101)$ and $f(200)$

Tags: calculus, functional-equations

I've been trying this question and I tried using Langrange's Mean Value Theorem but I don't know the derivative will help in getting the answer. Help?
The options are:

a)$ f(101) = f(202) + 8 $

b)$ f(101)= f(200) +2 $

c)$ f(101) = f(201) +1 $

d) None of these

Comment: Do you mean a relation like $f(101) - 7 \cdot 99^{201} \leqslant f(200) \leqslant f(101) + 7 \cdot 99^{201}$?

Comment: How to use MathJax, is explained in [MathJax help](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It's very simple, and if you don't understand that, how can you hope to understand the answers, here?

Comment: Since it's a multiple choice question, you can "cheat" by noticing that because constant functions satisfy the condition, it can't be the case that any of a, b, or c is always true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this as follows:$$|f(x+h) - f(x)| \le 7 |h|^{201}$$Or, if you see where this is going,$$\left| \frac{f(x+h) -f (x)}{h}\right| \le 7 |h|^{200}$$In other words,$$-7|h|^{200} \le \frac{f(x+h) -f (x)}{h} \le 7 |h|^{200}$$Take the limit as $h \to 0$. By squeeze theorem, it's zero. It is, therefore, a constant function because $f'(x) = 0$.

Comment: (i.e. the only $\alpha$ Holder continuous functions for $\alpha>1$ are constant)